# Best way to prevent oversized Buffer File?

Tags: c#, buffer, fileinfo

I want to delete a buffer File, filled by Values from a scale.
So far this here is my code. But it deletes the whole file after a defined file size is reached.

```
if(File.ReadAllBytes("buffer1").Length >= 50)
                {
                    File.Delete("buffer1");
                }
```

I am sure there is a better way. Without deleting the whole file and keeping the las values in it. But how?
Hope someone can help.

Comment: How are you filling the buffer file?

Comment: `...ReadAllBytes...` **All** bytes, and what if the file is `100 GB` long? When you want just size `if (new FileInfo(@"buffer1").Length >= 50) {...}`

Comment: I tryed FileInfo @ first, dont know why, but it didnt worked... I must have done something wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the first several values from a file, the best way to do it is to copy the rest of the values to a second file.  Then you can overwrite the original file with the new file.  Here is some example code.

```
    const string yourfile = "buffer1";
    const string tempfile = "buffer1edit.bin";

    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(yourfile);
    if (fi.Length > 50)
    {
        using (System.IO.FileStream originalfile = System.IO.File.Open(yourfile, System.IO.FileMode.Open),
            newfile = System.IO.File.Open(tempfile, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            originalfile.Seek(50, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            originalfile.CopyTo(newfile);
        }

        System.IO.File.Delete(yourfile);
        System.IO.File.Move(tempfile, yourfile);
    }
```